# Wordpress SQL LIKE statement with multiple values

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin to search through all the users by first name, last name, email etc. It is working as long as I only use 1 of the values like first name.
I need to add all the values to the select!

I already tried adding more by using ',' and OR statements but it isn't working.

```
$results = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE %s", "%".$_POST['search']."%");
```

EDIT: found it

Found it!

```
$results = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower(first_name) LIKE lower (%s) OR lower(last_name) LIKE lower(%s) LIKE lower(%s)OR lower(postcode) LIKE lower(%s)", "%".$_POST['search']."%", "%".$_POST['search']."%");
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a literal % to pass through `$wpdb->prepare` just double it. You don't need to be avoiding `$wpdb->prepare`.

Proof of concept:

```
var_dump($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title LIKE "%%%s%%"','Hello'));
```

So your query should be :

```
$results = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE %%%s%%",$_POST['search']);
```

[(more...)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97384/how-to-properly-sanitize-strings-without-wpdb-prepare/97388#97388)

**Update**

Use this for imploding OR :

```
$var[] = 'name LIKE "%%%s%%"';
$var_data[] = 'Hello';
$var[] = 'email LIKE "%%%s%%"';
$var_data[] = 'tt@tt.tt';
$var[] = 'date LIKE "%%%s%%"';
$var_data[] = 'Howdy';
var_dump($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE '.implode(' OR ',$var),$var_data));
```

Comment: But I need like: SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name, last_name, street, email LIKE %s", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you treating the object properly?  This would iterate over the values retrieved

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['username'] . '<br />';
}
```